# How can I keep wind from blowing out my gas fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

I have a gas fireplace insert (the kind with the permanent glass cover and automatic ignition). It exhausts out the wall, not a roof chimney.

In very windy weather, when this fireplace is running, a gust of wind occasionally will be blown in the flue and blow out the fireplace.
It detects this condition and attempts to re-ignite. This process can take about 30 seconds. On a very gusty day the fireplace might blow out every 15 minutes or so.

There is currently a flue hood which keeps out critters, but it doesn't seem to completely protect against the wind. Unfortunately I can't take a photo right now (not at the cabin) but it looks like this:

[image: flue cap]

Is there a way I can protect the flue more somehow and prevent this nuisance?

Comment: What kind of protection is there over the flue exit? Is there any sort of hood? If not, that would probably help.

Comment: A picture of the flue exit would help.

Comment: @freeman there is a hood, detail added.

Comment: How often does this actually happen and how long for the fireplace to re-ignite?

Comment: Could the wind instead be blowing *by* the vent, causing a vacuum (Venturi) effect rather than blowing into the vent?